# Why Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME through res.download?

Tags: node.js, express

I am using express API to send a file from the server the the request as such :

```
app.get('/download', async (req, res)=> {
  res.download(`${__dirname}/dl/myfile.mp4}` , 'myfile.mp4' )
});
```

The file is sent and downloaded however I get *Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type video/mp4*

How can I set the header to the correct mime type within res.download or perhaps somewhere else?

Comment: You can try to use `sendFile()`. This method takes `headers` as an option. So you can specify the content type here http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.sendFile

Comment: With sendFile I ran into bunch of other problems which was why I decided to use download instead. Apparently download a method that was introduced to omit bunch of setting in sendFile to begin with.

Comment: But download() method will automatically detect the file type.

Comment: @PrathameshMore that is why I asked the question.

Comment: I am just curious about why this is not working?